# Customized serialization of POJO to JSON in spring restTemplate

Tags: java, json, spring

I am using the spring restTemplate to make POSTs to an endpoint and want it to convert my POJO to JSON. This is being done already. I have a list and it converts to JSONArray and does it successfully. I want to modify it a bit though where instead of it being an array, I want it to be a JSON with a key being the name of the list variable, and the value being the list.
Example is:

```
List<Record> records;
```

The above would create a JSON of

```
{
"records": [
    {
        "name": "test",
        "address": "chicago"
    },
    {
        "name": "stack",
        "address": "overflow"
    },
    {
        "name": "etc",
        "address": "etc"
    }
]
```

Rather than being [{},{},{}]

Answer (score 0):

I think just simple create a DTO object which contains your List and return it. For instance:

```
public class SampleDTO{

  private List<Record> records;
  //getter setter
}
```

in the Controller, just return the `ResponseEntity` with the body is your `SampleDTO`

Hope this help.